# Apache Proxy for Node.js and Wordpress on same "Domain" but different paths

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, express, mod-proxy

Here is the case.
I have a Wordpress website running on my main domain say `http://www.example.com`.

`.htaccess` is enabled on server and I am using Wordpress permalinks to generate pretty URLs.

Now I have another application in Node.js (Express) which I have deployed on same server and is running on port number `3000`. So if I put `http://www.example.com:3000` it triggers my Expressjs app. and it is running flawlessly.

What I want is to run the Node.js application on a specific path from the same domain. For example, if I hit, `http://www.example.com/node` it should take user to my Node.js app which it is taking quite fine if I use Apache `mod_proxy`. But this works only for the `/` route of my Expressjs router. 
But I also have several other routes e.g. `/subscribe`, `/confirm` but none of them work. 
Following is my Apache config which I tried to make work by giving multiple `ProxyPass` directives but it doesn't work.

```
ProxyPass /node http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /node http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPass /node/subscribe http://127.0.0.1:3000/subscribe
ProxyPassReverse /node/subscribe http://127.0.0.1:3000/subscribe
```

The Express router is pretty basic and uses following app configuration:

```
var router  = express.Router();
app.use("/",router);

router.get("/",function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(templatepath + "index.html");
});

router.get("/subscribe",function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(templatepath + "subscribe.html");
});

router.get("*",function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(templatepath + "404.html");
});
```

When I try to load `http://www.example.com/node/subscribe` it simply loads the `*` route and displays the `404.html` template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working by modifying the Apache configuration file as follows:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPass ^/node/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /node/ http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Comment: Just went to your answer and found out that you were able to resolve this. Great that your solution is working now.